# Set my default address for auto-fill?

Tags: safari, email, contacts, auto-complete

Since updating to 10.7.2, the email addresses in my address book card seem to have re-prioritized themselves. Now when I use Auto-Fill, the wrong address pops up, and I don't see any way to change it.

Can I set a "primary" or default address in Address Book? *(I still hate this new version of Address Book by the way.)*

Or, can I select which address is used in auto-fill in Safari?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.  I went into address book and put my desired address as the first one on my card.  It worked.

Comment: How do you change the order? Can't find it on El Capitan, on an address book that uses iCloud.

Comment: @qnoid The fastest way to do it is probably to replace the contents of the first address / email address with your desired information. Then re-add the old one at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to make sure the address I wanted to use for Autofill was the top address in my Contacts entry.

Answer (score -1):

Select or make the contact you to use as your autofill then go to card menu and select "make this my card"  I hope this helps!

Comment: The question is not about selecting my card, the problem is the addresses listed on the card itself.